# Trying to identify a plant by its root

Tags: species-identification, botany, vegetation

My kids were digging through a pile of dirt I had made for them to play with (my son wants to do bike jumps off it) and they brought in the attached root. I never got to see what kind of vegetation was growing from it, and the kids can't remember what it looked like.

This is from our backyard in central Texas.

The closest I have found was potato dandelion but there are very little picture references to this.[image]